# @EnableOAuth2Sso and csrf

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-security

I am trying to build a complete [sample code](https://github.com/shahbour/microservices-security) for Gateway, UI , Resource . Every thing worked perfect except when i tried to do post .

I noticed first that i have double csrf one from gateway and one from the UI . So my decision *which i am not sure is the correct* was to disable csrf on UI and keep it on the gateway (Zuul Proxy) but i was not able to do that .

I could not tell what adapter i should extent `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

As soon i declare `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` the whole OAuth2Sso stop working and i got access denied and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` does not seem to do any thing.

At first i would like to disable csrf on `@EnableZuulProxy` and
`@EnableOAuth2Sso`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887380/3224122) I found out that `@EnableOAuth2Sso` should be on the same `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` if one exist or we will end up with having 2 Adapter , doing so fixed every thing

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                //.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                //.and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
}
```

On spring boot 1.5.8 I also add to set `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1016