# Request method 'POST' not supported when @EnableOAuth2Sso

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am receiving a `Request method 'POST' not supported` error when I `@EnableOAuth2Sso` on my Spring Boot 1.5.9 / Angular 5 app.

GET requests work fine, and the `JSESSIONID` cookie looks like it's setting itself just fine on the front-end.  Cookie is getting passed with all requests, and matches.

In the Response Header: `Status Code: 405` `Allow: GET, HEAD`

This is my first Stack Overflow question, I've done all of my usual sleuthing and can't seem to get to the bottom of this one.  I apologize in advance for any oversights in my asking / formatting of this question.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class CompanyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompanyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Relevant Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Autowired
    ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @PostMapping("companies")
    public Company createCompany(@Valid @RequestBody Company company) {
        logger.info("*** Starting POST request of company name: {}", company.getName());
        company = updateContacts(company); // pass updated contact info into the Contact DB
        companyRepository.save(company);
        logger.info("*** Successful POST request of company: {}, ID: {},", company.getName(), company.getId());
        return company;
    }
```

Config settings:

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=myID
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=mySecret
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://myserver.com/connect/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://myserver.com/connect/authorize
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid,profile,email
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://myserver.com/connect/userinfo
```

Angular service:

```
public updateCompany( companyData: Company ) {
  return this.http.post(this.url, companyData);
}
```

**Edit:**
I followed the advice of @theLearner below, but still wanted to add CSRF (XSRF) protection.  This is how I ended up doing it:
In app.module.ts add `HttpClientXsrfModule` to `imports` (I'm on Angular 5).
Remove `@EnableOAuth2Sso` from root `CompanyApp` class.
Config as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().
                and().
                csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

Comment: What url/api are you accessing when you get `Request method 'POST' not supported`?

Comment: api/companies - here is the full request header that is being generated: `POST /api/companies HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 278
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/auth/companies
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=41CF1089A5BF001351F378643685EFB2`

Comment: have you tried by disabling csrf protection in your spring security config?

Comment: I have, and it works, the problem is that 'everything' works - even requests without a cookie attached...

Comment: You mean to say everything works except the POST request? Or that disabling csrf made everything work?

Comment: ...but you gave me an idea, rather than trying to secure the entire app, maybe I'll try only securing the api endpoints...

Comment: well, only GET requests work - POST, PUT and DELETE all fail - sorry, I mean to say after I disable csrf all http OPTIONS work...

Comment: I am not on my laptop right now. Let me share a solution with you in half an hour

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear - disabling csrf basically removes the SSO - no redirect to the SSO page, no cookie or anything.  Also my question title says 'POST' not supported, but it would be more accurate to say only 'GET' supported as DELETE, PUT and others fail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following things you need to do.

1. In application properties add this config:

`security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3`

More info about this is  [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1016).

2. Since you have not posted your Spring security config yet, not sure how is it right now. But it should look like this:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableOAuth2Sso
   public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.csrf().disable() // or replace this with tour csrf token repository
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated();
   }
   ```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887380/2458858) explains if `@EnableOauth2Sso` is not used carefully it can really mess up entire security configuratiin

Comment: I upvoted it, but my reputation is too low for it to show, thank you again.  Another side note, seems like it works fine even if I comment out `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3` I think this may be a result of being on Spring Boot Starter version 1.5.9 vs an older version...

Comment: Maybe. That's why I included a link to the filter order issue page so that you can go through the details.